# Need help about fetchCurrenciesData

Tags: python

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import time


class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
        self.params = {
            'start': '1',
            'limit': '100',
            'convert': 'USD'
        }
        self.headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'X-CMC-PRO-API-KEY': 'my key',
        }

        self.orders = []


    def fetchCurrenciesData(self):
        r = requests.get(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, params=self.params).json()
        return r['data']


    def canBuy(self):
            #controlla se le operazioni di acquisto non sono chiuse
        for order in self.orders:
            if order['status'] == 'open':
                return False
        return True

impactBot = Bot()

while(1):
    now = datetime.now()
    currencies = impactBot.fetchCurrenciesData()
    print(currencies)
    i = 1 #incremento in percentuale
    r = 4 #valore sopra il quale fare partire l'operazione
    n = 0 #numero di valute cui prezzo ha subito un incremento migliore di i dall'ultima volta
    z = -1 #percentuale sotto la quale vendi la valuta
    bestCurrency = None #valuta con rivalutazione del prezzo maggiore

       #logica
    if impactBot.canBuy():
        print('Non ci sono posizioni aperte - Controllo se trovo valute che hanno guadagnato piu di (i)% nell ultima ora ')
        for currency in currencies:
            if not bestCurrency or currency['quote'] ['USD'] ['percent_change_1h'] > bestCurrency['quote'] ['USD'] ['percent_change_1h']:
                bestCurrency = currency
            if currency['quote'] ['USD'] ['percent_change_1h'] > i:
                       n = n +1
        if n > 4:
            print ('Ho trovato piu di quattro valute - Creo un nuovo ordine')
            newOrder = {
                'datetime': now,
                'symbol': currency['symbol'],
                'enterPrice': currency['quote'] ['USD'] ['price'], #prezzo con cui abbiamo acquistato
                'exitPrice': None,
                'status': 'open'
            }
            impactBot.orders.append(newOrder)

    else:
        print('Controllo gli ordini ancora aperti - Se si verifica la condizione di svalutazioneallora vendo')
        for currency in currencies:
            if currency['quote'] ['USD'] ['percent_change_1h']:
                for order in impactBot.orders:
                    if order['status'] == 'open' and order['symbol'] == currency['symbol']:

                               #vendi
                        order['status'] = 'close'
                        order['exitPrice'] = currency['quote'] ['USD'] ['price']

            #overview
    initialAmount = 10000
    profit = 0
    for order in impactBot.orders:
        if order['status'] == 'close':
            profit += initialAmount * order['exitPrice'] / order['enterPrice']
    finalAmount = initialAmount + profit
    print('Ho realizzato {len(impactBot.orders)} compravendite aono partito con {initialAmount}$ e adesso ne ho {finalAmount}$')


            #routine
    minutes = 10
    seconds = minutes * 60
    time.sleep(seconds)
```

This are the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andyduma/PycharmProjects/esercitazioni/Bot.py", line 38, in <module>
    currencies = impactBot.fetchCurrenciesData()
  File "/Users/andyduma/PycharmProjects/esercitazioni/Bot.py", line 24, in fetchCurrenciesData
    return r['data']
KeyError: 'data'
```

Comment: Seems like `data` key is not present in `r` dict. Check the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make requests like these you should make a condition to test the results so you can see what is going on. I can't be positive that my way of testing the error code is exactly how you should do it, but it is definitely in the ballpark.

```
def fetchCurrenciesData(self):
    r = requests.get(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, params=self.params).json()
    status = r['status']
    if 'error_code' not in [*status] or status['error_code'] == 0:
        #print(r) #uncomment if the next line throws an error
        return r['data']  
    
    raise ValueError(f"Error {status['error_code']}: {status['error_message']}")
```

and

```
while(1):
    now = datetime.now()
    try:
        currencies = impactBot.fetchCurrenciesData()
        print(currencies)
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
        break
```

If you look at the python example for [the API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Quick-Start-Guide) you are not doing it the way they tell you to. Your way may work regardless, but why invent your own solutions when the company that is providing you with the API has given you a copy/paste solution to use? They want you to create a Session and you have completely failed to do that.